# Get event for just newly added child node on firebase database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to get a trigger for newly added child node on reference path and get value for just the new data. But `event.data.val` returns all the value in that reference path.

Following is the cloud function code I am using:

```
exports.sendOfferNotification = functions.database.ref('/Users/{uid}/offers/New').onWrite(event => {
  // Only edit data when it is first created.
      // if (event.data.previous.exists()) {
      //   return;
      // }
      // Exit when the data is deleted.
      if (!event.data.exists()) {
        return;
      }
      // Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
      const original = event.data.val();
      console.log('New offer', event.params.uid, original);

});
```

I tried using `onUpdate` instead of `onWrite` but still same result.

Comment: An onWrite() database trigger will always receive all the data at the location you specify in ref(), whenever anything under that location changed.

Comment: Ya, I agree but onUpdate() also behaves the same. Any idea on how I can get only the newly added data? For e.g if there are 4 offers already under /New and when 5th one is added, I want to just retrieve the data of 5th one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it using `onCreate()` on the nested level of New/

```
exports.sendNotificationForImportantOffers = functions.database.ref('/Users/{uid}/offers/New/Important/{values}').onCreate(event => {
  // Only edit data when it is first created.
      // if (event.data.previous.exists()) {
      //   return;
      // }
      // Exit when the data is deleted.
      if (!event.data.exists()) {
        return;
      }
      // Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
      const original = event.data.val();
      console.log('New offer', event.params.uid, original);

});
```

Initially, I was trying to have one single function to listen to changes on all the nested level under New/ path but now I will have to monitor trigger for each sub-level separately with `onCreate()` which returns me only the newly added child.

Answer (score 3):

you could try this:

```
exports.sendOfferNotification = 
functions.database.ref('/Users/{uid}/offers/New/{values}') //notice this change
.onWrite(event => {
      if (!event.data.exists()){return};
      const original = event.params.values; //notice this change
      console.log('New offer', event.params.uid, original);
});
```

Comment: your approach for {values} helped but I had one more sub-layer and need to use onCreate() instead of onWrite(). So, I have posted my answer below.

Comment: This is perfect. If you are pushing data into your node and only want to get the results of the new node then do what J.Doe is doing... You simply can use onWrite and {values} and then access the new added push record that is found in the const original.